# TicTacToe endgame feedback in C#

Tags: c#, tic-tac-toe

I'm learning C# and currently having an assignment on Tic Tac Toe. I'd love to have some feedback on where I can improve.

I've managed to create the end game functions but I feel it could be improved. I'm just not sure how to do it and was hoping someone here could help me.

I hope the information I've provided is enough, `this.cells` is a multidimensional array containing the `Cell` objects:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains info about what kind of cell we're dealing with
/// </summary>
public enum Cell {
  Empty,
  Circle,
  Cross
}
```

**Below is the part I'm searching feedback on. Too many if statements? What could I have done different or better?**

```
/// <summary>
/// Check all possible combinations for the target cell
/// of winning the game (row, column, or slope).
///
/// Returns true if there is a win condition, false if there isn't.
/// </summary>
private bool IsGameOver(Cell cell) {
    // Row 1
    if (this.cells[0, 0] == cell && this.cells[0, 1] == cell && this.cells[0, 2] == cell) {
        return true;
    }

    // Row 2
    if (this.cells[1, 0] == cell && this.cells[1, 1] == cell && this.cells[1, 2] == cell) {
        return true;
    }

    // Row 3
    if (this.cells[2, 0] == cell && this.cells[2, 1] == cell && this.cells[2, 2] == cell) {
        return true;
    }

    // Clm 1
    if (this.cells[0, 0] == cell && this.cells[1, 0] == cell && this.cells[2, 0] == cell) {
        return true;
    }

    // Clm 2
    if (this.cells[1, 0] == cell && this.cells[1, 1] == cell && this.cells[1, 2] == cell) {
        return true;
    }

    // Clm 3
    if (this.cells[2, 0] == cell && this.cells[2, 1] == cell && this.cells[2, 2] == cell) {
        return true;
    }

    // Horizontal line 1
    if (this.cells[0, 0] == cell && this.cells[1, 1] == cell && this.cells[2, 2] == cell) {
        return true;
    }

    // Horizontal line 2
    if (this.cells[0, 2] == cell && this.cells[1, 1] == cell && this.cells[2, 0] == cell) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Naming

The enum `Cell` defines `Empty`, `Circle` and `Cross`. This values aren't cells in terms of an object, they are more like types.

For example: *Empty* is not a cell, but a cell can be *empty*

You can rename `Cell` to `CellType` to make it more clear.

## Comments

Comments are a good documentation. You did a great job with the `<summary>`-tag. But the comments like `// Row 1`, `// Row 2`, `// Clm 3` are not so good..

Robert C. Martin, who wrote the book "Clean Code" and many more, sad

> [Don’t Use a Comment When You Can Use a Function or a Variable](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/45372.Robert_C_Martin?page=2)

## Introduce Methods

We can wrap the if-statements into methods

```cs
bool IsFirstRowComplete(CellType cellType) {
    if (this.cells[0, 0] == cellType && this.cells[0, 1] == cellType && this.cells[0, 2] == cellType) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool IsSecondRowComplete(CellType cellType) {
    if (this.cells[1, 0] == cellType && this.cells[1, 1] == cellType && this.cells[1, 2] == cellType) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// ...
```

### Make them less complex

Since these methods return a Boolean we can return the boolean-expression itself

```cs
bool IsFirstRowComplete(CellType cellType) {
    return this.cells[0, 0] == cellType
           && this.cells[0, 1] == cellType
           && this.cells[0, 2] == cellType
}

bool IsSecondRowComplete(CellType cellType) {
    return this.cells[1, 0] == cellType
           && this.cells[1, 1] == cellType
           && this.cells[1, 2] == cellType
}

// ...
```

### Remove Duplication

The new methods `IsFirstRowComplete` and `IsSecondRowComplete` looks very similar. We can extract the main logic and wrap it into its own method.

```cs
bool IsRowComplete(CellType cellType, int row) {
    return this.cells[row, 0] == cellType
           && this.cells[row, 1] == cellType
           && this.cells[row, 2] == cellType
}

// ...
```

If you like you can now wrap this method into `IsFirstRowComplete` and so on

```cs
bool IsFirstRowComplete(CellType cellType, int row) {
    return IsRowComplete(cellType, 0);
}

// ...
```

### Introduce more Methods

We could finish here.. But we can make the code more clear if we wrap each check into a method

```cs
bool IsARowComplete(CellType cellType) {
    return IsFirstRowComplete(cellType, 0)
           || IsSecondRowComplete(cellType, 1)
           || IsThirdRowComplete(cellType, 2);
}

bool IsAColumnsComplete(CellType cellType) {
  return IsFirstColumnComplete(cellType, 0)
         || IsSecondColumnComplete(cellType, 1)
         || IsThirdColumnComplete(cellType, 2);
}

// ...
```

## After the Refactoring

```cs
bool IsGameOver(CellType cellType) {
    return IsARowComplete(cellType)
           || IsAColumnComplete(cellType)
           || IsAHorizontalComplete(cellType)
}
```

## Maybe a Bug

If the method `isGameOver` gets called with a `CellType` of type `Empty` it could return `true`

So maybe you need to check if the `cellType` is not `Empty`

Comment: Roman thank you so much for your time! I learned so much! <3

Comment: Well done! I'd have gone with `CellState` though =)